# Скрипт мешает выполниться media queries

Tags: css, javascript

Добрый вечер!

Проблема в следующем:

Есть адаптивный макет. Есть скрипт, точнее [плагин карусели](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/16/circular-content-carousel/). Данная карусель должна работать только если ширина экрана >= 533.

Вызываю данный плагин следующим образом:

```
if ( $(window).width() >= 533) {
    $('#ca-container').contentcarousel();
}
```

В случае, если ширина экрана меньше 533, слайдер должен перестать быть слайдером и преобразоваться в простой контент, если больше, то должен вновь становиться слайдером.

Используем медиа запрос:

```
@media (max-width: 550px) { }
```

Если уменьшаем страницу до < 550, блок, который должен из слайдера преобразоваться в контент пропадает. Отображается как надо, только после перезагрузки страницы (F5).

Обратное же действие, то есть увеличение экрана > 550, ломает слайдер.

Проблема 100% в js, так как, если отключить плагин слайдера, то преобразуется с первого раза и без перезагрузки страницы.

Это же, как я предполагаю, является причиной некорректного отображения данного и ниже следующего блока на мобильных устройствах в ландшафтной ориентации экрана.

Увидеть проблему наглядно можно [ЗДЕСЬ](http://krepezhstroy.ru/voltmobi/index.html).

Надеюсь на Вашу помощь.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, проблема в нем, так как он модифицирует элементы слайдера, но у этого дурного плагина нет метода "destroy", поэтому его прийдется написать самому, например такой:

```
$.fn.contentcarouselDestory = function (){
    this.unbind('.contentcarousel').find('*').unbind('.contentcarousel');
    this.find('.ca-nav').remove();
    this.find('.ca-wrapper').css('overflow', '');
    this.find('.ca-item').attr('style', '');
    return this;
};
```

И сделать "умную" инициализацию, в зависимости от размеров окна:

```
$.windowOnResize = function (){
    var init = $(window).width() >= 533;
    $('#ca-container')[init ? 'contentcarousel' : 'contentcarouselDestory']();
};

$(window).bind('resize', function (){
    // debounce
    clearTimeout($.windowOnResize.pid);
    $.windowOnResize.pid = setTimeout($.windowOnResize, 100);
});

$.windowOnResize();
```

Comment: Уважаемый @RubaXa, подскажите пожалуйста, где это все нужно прописать ... просто я в js человек новый, поэтому не могу сразу въехать ...

Comment: В это файле http://krepezhstroy.ru/voltmobi/js/script.js замените содержимое " Slider for desctop" на http://jsfiddle.net/yzQAe/1/

Comment: @RubaXa, к сожалению не работает ...

Comment: Значит вы что-то сделали не так, проверял на вашем сайте и оно работает, но с другой стороны, а зачем вам вообще так морочиться? Вы думаете что кто-то будет вашу страницу сжимать и смотреть? В реальности нет такого use case, у вас экран либо больше 533px, либо меньше.

Comment: Скопировал приведенный Вами код из jsfiddle и вставил в файл script.js

Таковы требования заказчика ...

Comment: Прошу прощения, все работает! Спасибо огромное!!!

@RubaXa, а не поможете вот с этим вопросом? - http://hashcode.ru/questions/223645/jquery-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-touch-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0

Comment: Сейчас гляну.